# When exporting my electron app the file size is 2.22 GB

Tags: macos, electron, export

I am encountering an issue on my mac where when I export my app using `npm run dist`, it exports with a file size of 2.22 GB. The first time I exported the app it was 30 MB. 
I did not make any new changes to it, so what is making it so large?

json file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xLJjXXOs5y_kVuGllno3lRhte2FTNCz1/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: What does your package.json look like?

Comment: @1252748 thats the google drive link